# (Python3) Linux and Windows Arrow Key pressed

Tags: python, linux, windows, terminal, arrow-keys

I was looking for a while now all over the Internet but I cant seem to find a unique way for Linux and Windows that allows to catch a arrow up, down etc. event.

With the `msvcrt` package on windows i found this solution:

```
from msvcrt import getch

while True:
    print ('Distance from zero: ' + str(pos))
    key = ord(getch())
    if key == 224: #Special keys (arrows, f keys, ins, del, etc.)
        key = ord(getch())
        if key == 80: #Down arrow
```

For Linux I used the `termios` package:

```
import sys,tty,termios
class _Getch:
    def __call__(self):
            fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
            old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
            try:
                tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
                ch = sys.stdin.read(3)
            finally:
                termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
            return ch

def get():
        inkey = _Getch()
        while(1):
                k=inkey()
                if k!='':break
        if k=='\x1b[A':
                print ("up")

def main():
        for i in range(0,20):
                get()

if __name__=='__main__':
        main()
```

I also found a Package that is supported by Linux and Windows: `keyboard`

```
import keyboard #Using module keyboard
while True:#making a loop
    try: #used try so that if user pressed other than the given key error will not be shown
        if keyboard.is_pressed(keyboard.KEY_DOWN):#if arrow down is pressed 
            print('You Pressed down Key!')
```

This seems to work great on Windows but not on Linux.

(I found all those implementations on Stack overflow.)

My goal is it to move my arrow up and down on different selections. Alternative methods to complete this task are welcome as well.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your question is with respect to catching arrow key events solely on the **terminal** or the **command prompt**. If that is the case, then using getch() for windows and termios+tty in Linux is the way to go, as you mentioned.

Alternate Cross Platform Methods Include:

1. On Linux the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) module is recommended in general, and you can also find the unofficial binaries for this module for windows support [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#curses), or also by running:

`pip install http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/xugyqnq9/curses-2.2-cp27-none-win32.whl`

2. The keyboard module mentioned in the question works on linux only with sudo permissions, as mentioned [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/keyboard/). You could also try [PyUserInput](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyUserInput), which seems to work on my Linux machine.

In general though you are better off implementing your own solution in msvcrt/ttty+termios, or using a GUI Libraries like Pygame or Tkinter (If the application does not specifically require to run on a terminal), which provide facilities for catching keyboard events.